# Heuristic for minimax - Board Games

Tags: artificial-intelligence, heuristics, 2d-games

I am implementing an AI player for [this](http://nickbentleygames.WordPress.com/2010/02/11/one-of-my-better-games-odd/) board game.

I am using AB minimax for search, but I am having trouble finding a good heuristic for the evaluation function. How should I approach this problem?

Answer (score 1):

You can use Neural Network with Evolution Programming. I mean, teach neural network in tournaments and use the "resulting neural network" as heuristic function.

Comment: the state space is exponential (impossible to store). I need to find a set of features for the board states.